# Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)

Tags: server, apache2, ssl

I've just started using letsencrypt on my server and it was running fine until I somehow massed it up. Now my Apache isn't starting any more and  `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log`, gives me:

```
[ssl:emerg] [pid 28687] AH02240: Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)
[ssl:emerg] [pid 28687] AH02312: Fatal error initialising mod_ssl, exiting.
```

I'm not sure where I should start looking for the answer. I'm using virtual hosts in separate files for each subdomain and the letsencrypt client took care of the ssl certificates for each.

I'm not sure where to look for the certificates mentioned in my apache2 error log, where they are set or where they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I dissabled the two virtual hosts I made last with `a2dissite` and now Apache2 is starting.